# How to restore ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-bionic.list

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management

I accidentally removed (rm)

- /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-bionic.list
- /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-bionic.list.save

therefore I would like to know:

1. What did I lose?
2. Am I right assuming that I will not get any update for packages installed via repos defined in these files?
3. Is there any way to restore them? Ex: from Ubuntu github repo ...?

Comment: Looks like you added the PPA: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu. Simply re-add that PPA.

Comment: Thanks @user535733 - your comment led me to https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make and then it was as easy as 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Xenial systems I have the similar files named

> ```
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list.save
> ```

They have only one uncommented line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial main
```

Which represents [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make?field.series_filter=bionic) with [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) utility.

You have to re-add it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
```

Note: without `*.list` file the system will change the package status to locally installed or obsolete, this is not recommended. In this particular case the PPA provides newer version, so you can't reinstall the `ubuntu-make` package without this PPA added to the system.